# Error when finding by string in database searchUsersWithQuery:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107436360'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Swift and im trying to get users by searching with their username, but im getting this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ToDo.FriendsViewController searchUsersWithQuery:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107436360'
> First throw call stack:
> (0x1ae4ae678 0x1a672bc80 0x1ae53efdc 0x1b1421828 0x1ae3f3d88 0x1ae534950 0x1b14024ac 0x1b0da5ff4 0x1b0da636c 0x1b0da3930 0x1b0da549c 0x1b07f1f00 0x1b07f18a4 0x1b07f0b24 0x1b07b3460 0x1b07b1764 0x1b07b0170 0x1b0699a4c 0x1b069913c 0x1b06991f8 0x1ae3f90ac 0x1ae3f8328 0x1ae3f6adc 0x1ae3f5818 0x1ae3f53f8 0x1f19ab4f8 0x1b081b8a0 0x1b081aedc 0x1b0a45598 0x104c90880 0x104c907f8 0x104c908fc 0x1d115edcc)

this is my code, any ideas why this exception occur? I couldn't find any information about how to do it right the right way so far.

```
class FriendsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var searchTextField : UITextField?
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    
    func addFriend(userID: String, friendID: String) {
        let userRef = db.collection("users").document(userID)
        userRef.updateData(["friends": FieldValue.arrayUnion([friendID])])
    }
    @IBAction func searchButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let usernameSearched = searchTextField?.text else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        searchUsers(usernameSearched) { users in
            print("Users found: \(users)")
        }
    }

    func searchUsers(_ usernameSearched: String, completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
        let db2 = Firestore.firestore()
        db2.collection("users").whereField("userName", isEqualTo: usernameSearched).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting docs: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion([])
                return
            }
            var users: [User] = []
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
                let profileImageURL = ""
                let user = User(email: email, profileImageURL: profileImageURL)
                users.append(user)
            }
            completion(users)
        }
    }
```

problem occurs specifically in this line as far as I understand `db2.collection("users").whereField("userName", isEqualTo: usernameSearched).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in`

Comment: The exception says that you tried to call a method on your view controller with the signature `searchUsersWithQuery:completion` but that method doesn't exist. The closest function you have shown has the signature `searchUsers:completion`. You need to look at the stack trace to determine where the method invocation is coming from

Comment: apparently your suggestion helped me, I couldn't find where its coming from, but creating new button and assigning searchbuttontapped function again solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: Probably your old button was linked to a function you had renamed or deleted.